# Delphi JsonDataObjects tuning

Tags: json, delphi

I Need to write and read large json file (eg. 50 MB).

After some benchmark [JsonDataObjects](https://github.com/ahausladen/JsonDataObjects) seems the fastest library avaible for Delphi.

JsonDataObjects has some compiler option for enable/disable feature.

I'm on IIS 10 isapi service, what directive i can enable disable for best performance?

Any other tips and trick for improve performance are welcome.

```
// Enables the progress callback feature
{$DEFINE SUPPORT_PROGRESS}

// Sanity checks all array index accesses and raise an EListError exception.
{$DEFINE CHECK_ARRAY_INDEX}

// JSON allows the slash to be escaped. This is only necessary if you plan to put the JSON string
// into a <script>-Tag because then "</" can't be used and must be escaped to "<\/". This switch
// enables the special handling for "</" but makes the parser slightly slower.
{.$DEFINE ESCAPE_SLASH_AFTER_LESSTHAN}

// When parsing a JSON string the pair names are interned to reduce the memory foot print. This
// slightly slows down the parser but saves a lot of memory if the JSON string contains repeating
// pair names. The interning uses a hashset to store the strings.
{$DEFINE USE_STRINGINTERN_FOR_NAMES}

// Use an optimized NewInstance implementation. It skips the initialization of the interface table.
// and seals the TJsonArray and TJsonObject classes because it isn't safe to derive from them.
{$DEFINE USE_FAST_NEWINSTANCE}

//{$IF CompilerVersion < 28.0} // XE6 or older
// The XE7 compiler is broken. It doesn't collapse duplicate string literals anymore. (RSP-10015)
// But if the string literals are used in loops this optimization still helps.

// Optimizes the following pattern:
//   O['Name'][MyPropStr]
//   O['Name']['MyProp'].
// where the second O['Name'] is handled very fast by caching the pointer to the 'Name' string literal.
{$DEFINE USE_LAST_NAME_STRING_LITERAL_CACHE}
//{$IFEND}

 // When parsing the JSON string, the UStrAsg calls are skipped for internal strings what eliminates
// the CPU locks for those string assignments.
{$DEFINE USE_FAST_STRASG_FOR_INTERNAL_STRINGS}

{$IFDEF AUTOREFCOUNT}
// Delphi's ARC is slow (RSP-9712). This switch enables a faster ARC handling and even skips memory
// barrier were possible.
    {$DEFINE USE_FAST_AUTOREFCOUNT}
{$ENDIF AUTOREFCOUNT}

{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  // When adding JSON object properties with string literals, the string literals are stored directly
  // in the "Name" field instead of using UStrAsg that creates a new heap string. This improves the
  // performance as no string is copied and it slighly reduces the memory usage.
  // The string literals are only used if they are in the main instance or the DLL that contains the
  // JsonDataObjects unit. Other string literals are copied using UStrAsg because unloading the DLL
  // that holds them would cause access violations.
  // This has no effect when parsing JSON strings because then there are no string literals.
  {$DEFINE USE_NAME_STRING_LITERAL}

  // Reading a large file >64 MB from a network drive in Windows 2003 Server or older can lead to
  // an INSUFFICIENT RESOURCES error. By enabling this switch, large files are read in 20 MB blocks.
  {$DEFINE WORKAROUND_NETWORK_FILE_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES}

  // If defined, the TzSpecificLocalTimeToSystemTime is imported with GetProcAddress and if it is
  // not available (Windows 2000) an alternative implementation is used.
  {$DEFINE SUPPORT_WINDOWS2000}

{$ENDIF MSWINDOWS}
```